# RPG 4: Cast signed integer to Date and Time

Tags: rpgle

I need cast timestamp (in Signed Int) to Date and Time.
How can I do it?

Idea:

```
D  stampint                     10I 0     //- value: '1455554435' - input parm 
D  Varprint                     10A      
D  Varprint2                     8A 0     

 /free
   Varprint  = %char(%date( (<cast to timestamp> stampint) :*MDY));
   Varprint2 = %char(%time( (<cast to timestamp> stampint) :*HMS));
   dsply Varprint;
   dsply Varprint;
   inlr = *on;
   return ;
 /End-free

 Objective result:
   DSPLY 02/15/2016
   DSPLY 16:40:35
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: Sorry, I put the question so fast that I didn't report it correctly.

The objective is to be able to report date and time, regardless of the type of variable. Var1 can be * CHAR or numeric (Packed). Varprint and Varprint2 are a example, but I would like to know how to cast from type I to type Z.

I have tried to use:

```
D timestmp          Z inz('1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000')
D result            Z inz('0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000')
... code..
 /free
   result = timestmp + %seconds(stampint);
   dsply result;
 /end-free
```

But result is wrong.

I've tried too:

```
Varprint  = %char(%date( %editc(stampint:'Z') :*MDY));
```

But it give compilation error: *RNF7416- The types of the right and left hand side do not ma
the EVAL operation.

Comment: What format is the integer?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error, runtime error or logic error? That would be a really helpful tidbit to share.

Comment: Hey Rajiir, great question. When looking for guidance it is SO best practice to describe what you have already tried and where you became blocked. This context will facilitate the best, most meaningful answers possible. Good luck!

Comment: My fault, I update info. I hope to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use %timestamp(), except that an 10 digit integer isn't big enough for a actual timestamp... 6 digits for a date and 6 digits for a time (including seconds)

Best bet would be to use `%editc(sampint:'X')` to convert to a character string with lead zeros, then %subst() to break out the date and what I assume is only 'HH:MI' for a time...

If you want to convert to an actual time type, you'll need to concat ':00' for seconds in order to use %time();

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us an example value for stampint? And for that value, what you want varprint and varprint2 to be?

Update. Since stampint is a number of seconds, then assuming it is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970, do the following:

```
   dcl-s ts timestamp;                                 
   dcl-s d date;                                       
   dcl-s t time;                                       
   dcl-s stampint int(10) inz(1000000000);                  

   ts = Z'1970-01-01-00.00.00' + %seconds(stampint);   
   d = %date(ts);                                      
   t = %time(ts);                                      
   dsply (d);                                          
   dsply (t);                                          
   return;
```

To get the date as a character value in *MDY form:

```
   varprint = %char(%date(ts) : *mdy);
   varprintt = %char(%time(ts) : *hms);
```

Comment: I update info. stampint is the num of seconds in unix format.